# AWS Appsync Multi-table BatchPutItem Returns Null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I've been following the tutorial for batch operations:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#multi-table-batch

When I tried to do a multi-table batch, I get a null response even though the objects are successfully submitted to dynamodb.

This is my mutation:

```html
mutation sendReadings {
  recordReadings(
    tempReadings: [
      {sensorId: 1, value: 85.5, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:05.000+08:00"},
      {sensorId: 2, value: 85.7, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:06.000+08:00"},
      {sensorId: 3, value: 85.8, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:07.000+08:00"},
      {sensorId: 4, value: 84.2, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:08.000+08:00"},
      {sensorId: 5, value: 81.5, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:09.000+08:00"}
    ]
    locReadings: [
      {sensorId: 1, lat: 47.615063, long: -122.333551, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:05.000+08:00"},
      {sensorId: 2, lat: 47.615163, long: -122.333552, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:06.000+08:00"}
      {sensorId: 3, lat: 47.615263, long: -122.333553, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:07.000+08:00"}
      {sensorId: 4, lat: 47.615363, long: -122.333554, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:08.000+08:00"}
      {sensorId: 5, lat: 47.615463, long: -122.333555, timestamp: "2018-02-01T17:21:09.000+08:00"}
    ]) {
    locationReadings {
      sensorId
      timestamp
      lat
      long
    }
    temperatureReadings {
      sensorId
      timestamp
      value
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the response returns null:

> ```
> {
>   "data": {
>     "recordReadings": {
>       "locationReadings": null,
>       "temperatureReadings": null
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Request Mapping Template:

> ```
> ## Convert tempReadings arguments to DynamoDB objects
> #set($tempReadings = [])
> #foreach($reading in ${ctx.args.tempReadings})
>     $util.qr($tempReadings.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($reading)))
> #end
>
> ## Convert locReadings arguments to DynamoDB objects
> #set($locReadings = [])
> #foreach($reading in ${ctx.args.locReadings})
>     $util.qr($locReadings.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($reading)))
> #end
>
> {
>     "version" : "2018-05-29",
>     "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
>     "tables" : {
>         "LocationReadingTable": $utils.toJson($locReadings),
>         "TemperatureReadingTable": $utils.toJson($tempReadings)
>     }
> }
> ```

Response Mapping Template:

> ```
> ## If there was an error with the invocation
> ## there might have been partial results
> #if($ctx.error)
>     ## Append a GraphQL error for that field in the GraphQL response
>     $utils.appendError($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.message)
> #end
> ## Also returns data for the field in the GraphQL response
> $utils.toJson($context.result.data)
> ```

The code is pretty much identical to the tutorial. I checked the logs and the response is being sent but it's not being captured so either my code is off or there is a bug on AWS's side. Can anyone reproduce this or is able to get a response when doing a multi-table BatchPutItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for a very detailed question, it certainly helped me debug your issue. So, in order to fix your issue, you need to tweak your response mapping template. I was able to reproduce the issue with null response on my end. The reason being that the shape of the multi-table batch put response is of this format:

```
"result": {
    "data": {
        "TemperatureReadingTable": [
            {
                "value": 85.5,
                "sensorId": "1",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:05.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "value": 85.7,
                "sensorId": "2",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:06.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "value": 85.8,
                "sensorId": "3",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:07.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "value": 84.2,
                "sensorId": "4",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:08.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "value": 81.5,
                "sensorId": "5",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:09.000+08:00"
            }
        ],
        "LocationReadingTable": [
            {
                "lat": 47.615063,
                "long": -122.333551,
                "sensorId": "1",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:05.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "lat": 47.615163,
                "long": -122.333552,
                "sensorId": "2",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:06.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "lat": 47.615263,
                "long": -122.333553,
                "sensorId": "3",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:07.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "lat": 47.615363,
                "long": -122.333554,
                "sensorId": "4",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:08.000+08:00"
            },
            {
                "lat": 47.615463,
                "long": -122.333555,
                "sensorId": "5",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-01T17:21:09.000+08:00"
            }
        ]
    },
```

So, the `$context.result.data` will return you an object with `TemperatureReadingTable` and `LocationReadingTable` as its fields. However, you are applying `$util.toJson` to resolve the type `RecordResult`, which has `temperatureReadings` and `locationReadings` as child fields.

Please update your Response Mapping template with the following definition, and it will work for you:

```
  #if($ctx.error)
      ## Append a GraphQL error for that field in the GraphQL response
      $utils.appendError($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.message)
  #end

  {
      "temperatureReadings": $util.toJson(${ctx.result.data.TemperatureReadingTable}),
      "locationReadings": $util.toJson(${ctx.result.data.LocationReadingTable})
  }
```

Moreover, I'd encourage you enable CloudWatch logs from the Settings page of the Console, with `ALL` as the option. This will log Request/Response headers, the resolved Request/Response templates, Tracing information, etc. So it'll help you identify issues like these quickly by looking at the content of the request/response templates.

Thank you for bringing this issue, we will update the documentation, if it does not mention this.

Comment: Hey just double checked the documentation and it seems to be __right__. The only difference from the documentation to your example is that the DataSource names in your examples are `LocationReadingTable ` and `TemperatureReadingTable `, while in the documentation they are `locationReadings ` and `temperatureReadings ` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did check the logs but unfortunately couldn't figure out the syntax to pull it off so this was helpful. The documentation is off because the response mapping template for BatchPutItem says to return $utils.toJson($ctx.result.data) which won't work. It should be like how you showed above. While you guys are fixing the documentation, you guys should also fix the sendReadings mutation example under multi-table batch. All of the sensorIds are set as "sensorId: 1" but this won't work since the sensorId is the primary key.